# Hamming code extension

Tags: c#, hamming-code

I have taken the code from this website of Hamming code. If I wanted to implement it on 12 bits of message and 7 bits of Parity what changes do I have to do? I have added till DI[11] and CI[6] bit couldn't get to inter-prate it's logic

```
 string NrBinary;
 long pp, Key=8, number;
 double x, y;

 Console.WriteLine("Give binary value till 12 bit: ");

 NrBinary = Console.ReadLine();

 if (NrBinary.Length <= 12)
 {
     if (NrBinary.Length == 1) 
        NrBinary = "000000000000" + NrBinary;

     if (NrBinary.Length == 2) 
        NrBinary = "00000000000" + NrBinary;

     if (NrBinary.Length == 3) 
        NrBinary = "0000000000" + NrBinary;

     if (NrBinary.Length == 4) 
        NrBinary = "000000000" + NrBinary;

     if (NrBinary.Length == 5) 
        NrBinary = "00000000" + NrBinary;

     if (NrBinary.Length == 6) 
        NrBinary = "0000000" + NrBinary;

     if (NrBinary.Length == 7) 
        NrBinary = "000000" + NrBinary;

     if (NrBinary.Length == 8) 
        NrBinary = "00000" + NrBinary;

     if (NrBinary.Length == 9) 
        NrBinary = "0000" + NrBinary;

     if (NrBinary.Length == 10) 
        NrBinary = "000" + NrBinary;

     if (NrBinary.Length == 11) 
        NrBinary = "00" + NrBinary;

     if (NrBinary.Length == 12) 
        NrBinary = "0" + NrBinary;

     pp = NrBinary.Length;
     number = Convert.ToInt64(NrBinary);
     Console.WriteLine("PP = " + pp);

     for (Key = 0; Key < pp; ++Key)
     {
                x = Math.Pow(2, Key) - 1;
                y = pp + Key;

                if (x >= y)
                {
                    goto Mess;
                }
     }

     Mess:
     Console.WriteLine("Controlled bit needed Key = " + Key + "\n");

     long[] parity = new long[pp];
     long[] DI = new long[pp];
     long[] CI = new long[Key];

     DI[0] = number % 10;
     DI[1] = (number / 10) % 10;
     DI[2] = (number / 100) % 10;
     DI[3] = (number / 1000) % 10;
     DI[4] = (number / 10000) % 10;
     DI[5] = (number / 100000) % 10;
     DI[6] = (number / 1000000) % 10;
     DI[7] = (number / 10000000) % 10;
     DI[8] = (number / 100000000) % 10;
     DI[9] = (number / 1000000000) % 10;
     DI[10] = (number / 10000000000) % 10;
     DI[11] = (number / 100000000000) % 10;

     CI[0] = DI[11] ^ DI[0] ^ DI[1];
     CI[1] = DI[1] ^ DI[2] ^ DI[3];
     CI[2] = DI[3] ^ DI[4] ^ DI[5];
     CI[4] = DI[5] ^ DI[6] ^ DI[7];
     CI[5] = DI[7] ^ DI[8] ^ Convert.ToInt64(DI[9]);
     CI[6] = CI[1] ^ CI[2] ^ CI[3] ^ CI[4] ^ CI[5] ^ CI[6];

     Console.WriteLine("\n  = " + CI[0] + "" + CI[1] + "" + CI[2] + "" + CI[3] + "" + CI[4] + "" + CI[5] + "" + CI[6] + "\n");
     Console.Write("Bit with Hamming code: ");
     Console.WriteLine(DI[11] + "" + DI[10] + "" + DI[9] + "" + DI[8] + "" + DI[7] + "" + DI[6] + "" + DI[5] + "" + DI[4] + "" + DI[3]
            + "" + DI[2] + "" + DI[1] + "" + DI[0] + "" + CI[6] + "" + CI[5] + "" + CI[4] + "" + CI[3] + "" + CI[2] + "" + CI[1] + "" + CI[0]);
            /*Console.WriteLine(DI[7] + "" + DI[6] + "" + DI[5] + "" + DI[4] + "" + CI[3] + "" + DI[3]
            + "" + DI[2] + "" + DI[1] + "" + CI[2] + "" + DI[0] + "" + CI[1] + "" + CI[0]);*/
     }
     else
     {
         Console.WriteLine("\n\n 8 bit character maximally:)");
     }

     Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Which hamming coded?  See webpage : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_code.

Comment: I have updated the code but it gives IndexOutofRange exception on CI[5] and CI[6]

Comment: change from long to ULong.  No need to ConvertToInt64.  I suspect that you are trying to convert negative zero to a Int64

Comment: The for loop where key=0; key<pp; ++key
It runs 5 times! Then x value exceeds y and goes to MESS. Is there any way to make it through 5?

Comment: Why is x,y declared as double?  Make them ULong also.  You will need to cast (ULong)Math.Power() to a ULong.

Comment: It looks like the key number you chose is causing code to go to mess.  Look at wbpage.   Total bits pp  (11) = DataBits (8) + parity (3). Your total number of data bits = 11 (max 2048 - 1) which is x.  So key size (data bits) + parity must be <= 11.  So I think you have an error :  if (NrBinary.Length <= 12) should be <= 11.